# Issues with Logstash configuration file

Tags: elastic-stack

I am able to successfully run elasticsearch and kibana on windows but whenever I run the configuration file of logstash, it says :

> No log4j2 configuration file could be recognized.

I have prepared a configuration file and stored it in the same directory as logstash. For running the configuration file I am using the command -
`logstash -f "Configuration file path"`. Please Help.

Comment: Can you show us the configuration file in question?

Comment: Is your configuration file path relative or absolute? It could be related to this https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/6369.

Comment: input {
 file{
  path => "C:\Users\Dell -\Desktop\ELK\nessus_sample.csv"
  start_position => "beginning"
  sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
filter{
 csv {
  seperator => ","
  
  colums => ["Plugin ID", "CVE", "CVS", "Risk", "Host", "Protocol", "Port", "Name", "Synopsis", "Description", "Solution", "See also", "Plugin output"]
     }

 mutate {convert => ["Plugin ID", "integer"]}
 mutate {convert => ["Port", "integer"]}         
 
}
output {
  elasticsearch { 
  hosts => "localhost:9200"
  index => "Nessus"
  document_type => "Scanned_ip"
 }
  stdout { }
}